# Java's APT tool clashes Debian's APT

Tags: java, ant

I have Ant's build script generated by Weblogic Integration, one of the tasks is java apt task. But instead of running /bin/apt ant  invokes Debian's /usr/bin/apt. How do you get around this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Amend the PATH in the build sesssion

```
export PATH=/bin:$PATH
```

Then first the apt in /bin will be found and used.